# Characteristic function of discret random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, characteristic-functions

I try to show the following:

> Suppose $(X_n),n\geq1$ is a sequence of random variables with uniform distribution on $\{1/n,\dots,n/n \}$. Show that $(X_n)$ converges in distribution to a random variable $X\sim U(0,1)$

So I try to show that the characteristic function $\Phi_{X_n}(t)\to \Phi_{X}(t)$ which implies convergence in distribution.

Since I have a discrete RV the characteristic function looks like this:
$$\Phi_{X_n}(t)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n e^{itk} P(X_n=k)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n e^{itk}\frac{1}{n}$$
And the characteristic function of the limit looks like this

$$\Phi_{X_n}(t)=\int\limits_{0}^1 e^{itX}\mathrm{d}P=\frac{e^{ibt}-e^{iat}}{i(b-a)t}=\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}$$

Now I have to show that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n e^{itk}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}$$

But how can I do this and is this possible with convergence of a discrete measure to a contrinuous..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in the expression of the characteristic function. We have that
$$
\varphi_{X_n}(t)=\operatorname Ee^{itX_n}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^ne^{itk/n}.
$$
The sum
$$
\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^ne^{itk/n}
$$
is a [right Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) that converges to
$$
\int_0^1e^{itx}\mathrm dx
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Where does $\frac{k}{n}$ come from?

Comment: @Alex The random variable $X_n$ has the uniform distribution on $\{1/n,\ldots,n/n\}$ for every $n\ge1$.